# Installing a .tar.bz2 in windows

Tags: python

I am a newbie to installing python extensions working on Windows 7, running Python 2.6 -  I need to install the Levenshtein library from

http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/downloads/detail?name=python-Levenshtein-0.10.1.tar.bz2&can=2&q=

When I unzip the downloaded file, it gives me the following list of files:

- COPYING
- gendoc.sh
- Levenshtein.c
- Levenshtein.h
- MANIFEST
- NEWS
- PKG-INFO
- README
- setup.cfg
- setup.py
- StringMatcher.py

How do I install the Levenshtein library so I could import and use it into my python code?

Comment: I am REALLY a newbie when it comes to installing this stuff, so any kind of details would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you read the README?

Comment: It's unfortunate that you ran into a library in such a bad shape. Usually they have a maintainer who puts it up on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) so it can be installed via `pip install <library name>`. I *think* you can still use `pip` on a source tarball but I don't know enough about packaging magic to give an answer.

Comment: Yes. I can't find anything to help me there

Comment: You can do `python setup.py install` as mentioned in the official Python 2.7.3 documentation (http://docs.python.org/install/index.html)

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: When I do the python setup.py install, should I do that in the python command line. How do CD (switch directories) in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is quite a large section of the documentation easily found by doing some **research**.

http://docs.python.org/install/index.html

It appears that you will want to run:

```
python setup.py install --prefix="\Temp\Python"
```

to install modules to the \Temp\Python directory on the current drive.

Some more info:

> If you don’t choose an installation directory—i.e., if you just run
>   setup.py install—then the install command installs to the standard
>   location for third-party Python modules.
>
> The default installation directory on Windows was C:\Program Files\Python under Python 1.6a1, 1.5.2, and earlier.

Comment: I apologize for my newbiness. I've read the documentation for it. My problem is in the details: do i type the python setup.py install in the command line. Also, what is the prefix.

Comment: i added some more info plus the link to the documentation that i had forgotten earlier. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Python already installed on on you PATH, you can do this:

```
python setup.py install
```

However, it seems to have a compiled extension so you will probably also need a complete Windows development environment to install that (it is a source distribution). So if you don't it may not work. Your best bet would be to find that as an MSI package, if you can.